# Passing object reference through socket?

Tags: java

Is there a way to pass object reference through socket?

Say I have a client connected to server and I want to pass that client object reference to the server through the socket. Is that possible? If yes, how? And is it recommended? Or there are alternatives?

Comment: Why do you need to pass reference instead of object? If client and server lives on separate JVM's object reference won't be useful becuase object livies only on one of the JVMs. If client and server live on same JVM you should use in-process communication e.g. public static queue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I suppose they are running on different JVM !!!

Comment: I am trying to implement a chat.. and I cant find a way printing all the msgs in each client's OWN console

Comment: Then you need to send a copy, not a reference

Comment: Why a copy? how will it know to print the msgs in the right console?

Comment: Serialize the object and pass it across the socket.

Comment: @Rouki: each client has only one console, right? in that case, the client knows the console implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "reference" you actually mean a Java reference, then no:

You can't pass that to another machine (or even another process) for several reasons:

- Java doesn't let you access the actual reference value (you can only de-reference it, i.e. access the object/value behind the reference)
- Even if you could, the value would have no meaning outside of the original process (which would be tolerable, if you want to handle it like a handle/token)

Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be better to give away your own ID of some sort (numeric, for example), keep a map from those IDs to the actual objects and pass the ID to through the connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can not send a refference of an object because in normal cases, the server and the clients run in different jvms.

you can send an copy of the object

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to actually achieve. Why don't you create client+server architecture where each client is a server as well. This is how it works in many protocols where there is a need of a behavior where a client can connect to a server and also other client can connect to this client. Use different ports for your client and server connections. You should be good.